# Issue regarding running rake db:seed task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, database-migration, rake-task

I have an existing rails project and I am using postgres database and after successful execution of bundle exec rake db:migrate command when I am going to execute the bundle exec rake db:seed command then it throws me the following error.

rake aborted!
PG::DuplicateTable: ERROR:  relation "schema_migrations" already exists

I have commented out the lines where the definition of the schema_migration table creation is stored such as in the development_structure.sql and test_structure.sql files. But it is still throwing me the error.

I don't know from where the schema_migration table is being created. There is no schema_migration.rb file in my project.

Pleas help me to fix this. Thanks in advance!

This is my error log.

```
  rake aborted!
  PG::DuplicateTable: ERROR:  relation "schema_migrations" already exists
 : CREATE TABLE "schema_migrations" ("version" character varying(255) NOT NULL) 
 /home/bit/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-2.3.18/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:227:in `rescue in log'
 /home/bit/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-2.3.18/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:204:in `log'
 /home/bit/Development/app2/application/lib/core_extensions/postgresql_adapter/reconnect.rb:26:in `execute'
 /home/bit/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-2.3.18/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:109:in `create_table'
 /home/bit/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-2.3.18/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:371:in `initialize_schema_migrations_table'
 /home/bit/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-2.3.18/lib/active_record/migration.rb:441:in `initialize'
 /home/bit/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rails-2.3.18/lib/tasks/databases.rake:193:in `new'
 /home/bit/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rails-2.3.18/lib/tasks/databases.rake:193:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
 /home/bit/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
 /home/bit/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:seed => db:seed:common => db:seed:original =>    db:abort_if_pending_migrations
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's OK to drop your data locally, try

```
rake db:drop db:create db:migrate
```

and then seed again. I've had similar issues in the past where I deleted a migration without properly rolling it back and this was the solution.

If you need to keep it, open the rails database (`rails db` from terminal) and try

```
drop table schema_migrations
```

(Run the migrations with `db:migrate` again after this)

Edit: This has not solved the issue yet, but it seems there may be other issues that need to be factored in. OP cannot launch rails console and receives

```
undefined local variable or method `vars' for #<Rails::Generator::Commands::Create:0x00000001ca2578>
```

as the error message each time - if anyone has ideas here, please add an answer!

Comment: Yes, It is still there.

Comment: You could also try `ActiveRecord::Migration.drop_table(:schema_migrations)` from the rails console to see if that works

Comment: after running that command ActiveRecord::Migration.drop_table(:schema_migrations) , what I need to do? Give the full sequence.

Comment: OK: Load rails console, run the above line, exit the rails console and run `rake db:migrate` again

Comment: rails console opened. I am using rails 2.1.5 , so I need to write script/console instead of writing rails c

Comment: Ahh, I didn't realise you were running a version of Rails that old! Did 'ActiveRecord::Migration.drop_table(:schema_migrations)' work?